# kindle fire @media

Tags: css, email, media, kindle-fire

I am trying to design an email that renders uniquely in the native Kindle Fire email client.  I am able to pickup on the initial horizontal view using the following media query:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 590px) and (max-device-width:1014px){
/*kindle*/
    #desktop { display:none}
    #kindle { display:block !important}
}
```

...

```
<div class="mobile" id="kindle" style="display:none">Kindle Fire</div>
<div id="desktop">This is the desktop view</div>
```

The problem is that when I rotate the device to landscape, the media query is lost, when I rotate it back it's still lost.  I have tried using the orientation conditional statement but that doesn't seem to work at all.  Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

for orientation based CSS just use min-width or min-height. Do not use "device". That's what's hosing you up. Device queries do not detect orientation changes.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work for me for landscape view but I haven't checked it against other tablet devices.

```
/** Kindle Fire Landscape **/
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 600px) and (max-device-width: 1280px) {

}
```